# How to pickle TPOT fitted pipeline?

Tags: scikit-learn, pickle, tpot, scikit-learn-pipeline

I'm using the TPOT classifier, and after training the model, I want to save the best pipeline; I can get it using.

```py
model.fitted_pipeline_
```

This is an example of one of the outputs:

```py
Pipeline(steps=[('extratreesclassifier',
                  ExtraTreesClassifier(criterion='entropy', max_features=0.1,
                                       min_samples_split=8))])
```

But when I try to pickle this object using `joblib.dump` I get this error:

```py
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'tpot.operator_utils.ExtraTreesClassifier__bootstrap'>: it's not found as tpot.operator_utils.ExtraTreesClassifier__bootstrap
```

So the question is: how can I pickle the trained pipeline? Thanks in advance!

In case this might affect: The training is inside a class and it's called using a train() method, then the pipeline is returned from this method and another one makes the dump. I can't change this structure by a design constrain.

Comment: Maybe a bit too long ago, but maybe your problem was solved in the meantime. If you only dump the `model.fitted_pipeline_` with joblib, you should be able to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the `steps` attribute in the fitted pipeline.

Below is the code:

```
model = model.fitted_pipeline.steps[-1][1]
joblib.dump(model, "/path/to/pickle")
```

Comment: This seems wrong, as you'd be saving only part of the fitted_pipeline_, instead of all of it, as the author seems to want.